# Nested list sort

Tags: python

How do I append two values to a key in dictionary

It is throwing error str object has no attribute append

```
score_list={}
for _ in range(int(input())):
    score=float(input())
    name=input()
    if score in score_list:
        score_list[score].append(name)
    else:
        score_list[score]=name
new_list=[]
for score in score_list:
    new_list.append([score,score_list[score]])
new_list.sort()
```

Comment: Could you add your expected output? Is not clear what do you want to sort.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a `list` to your dict - not the string directly. Three ways I know of, from worst to best.

---

You can either use a normal dict and change your code to

> ```
> score_list={}
> for _ in range(int(input())):
>     score=float(input())
>     name=input()
>     if score in score_list:
>         score_list[score].append(name)
>     else:
> ```

```
        score_list[score] = [name]  # add as 1-elem list
```

---

or use [`dict.setdefault(key,defaultvalue)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

> ```
> score_list={}
> for _ in range(int(input())):
>     score=float(input())
>     name=input()
> ```

```
    k = score_list.setdefault(score,[]) # create key if needed with empty list
    k.append(name)
```

---

or use a [`collections.defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
score_list=defaultdict(list)
```

> ```
> for _ in range(int(input())):
>     score=float(input())
>     name=input()
> ```

```
    score_list[score].append(name)  # defaultdict handles list creation for you
```

The last method is most performant - `setdefault(score,[])` creates lots of empty default-lists that are not used if the key already exists.

---

If you need a top n result, you can create it directly from the [dictionaries item()s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
n = 5
top_n = sorted(score_list.items(), reverse=True) [:n]  # sorts by max score first 
# top_n  is a list of tuples:  [ (10000,["a","b","c"]) , (9999, ["b"]), ... ]
```

Comment: the  other answer was deleted, the link can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you need to change the line:

```
score_list[score]=name
```

to:

```
score_list[score]=[name]
```

In your current version you are assigning the string `name` to `score_list[score]`, so you need to change to a list hence the change.